# DotNetOpenAuth I Need Send Long string in FetchResponse

Tags: openid, dotnetopenauth

When I send Long string in FetchResponse

throw execption

Invalid URI: The Uri string is too long.

Answer (score 0):

AX, or any other OpenID extension, is not designed to carry large payloads.  If you have an image or other large binary data to transmit, it's better to make the image accessible via a URL and then transmit the URL over AX.